# PayPal Checkout with Multiple Items with Quantuty - Unknown Error

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying send a PayPal multiple items with quantity and amount in a shopping cart. When i try to send the following i get a unknown error. i dont know why

```
<form name="check_out_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sales@ss.com"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>



                     <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Featured: 3"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="9.95"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="3"/>

                      <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="2"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Standard: 2"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.95"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="2"/>





                      <input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="Career"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.sss.com/welcome.php?id=success"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="return_cancel" value="http://www.sss.com/welcome.php"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="id|1-custom|1-fea|9.95|3|29.85-std|2.95|2|5.9-total|"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.sss.com/ipn.php"/>
                      <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Complete Upgrade">
                      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Pay now"/>
                    </form>
```

I cant figure out what i am doing wrong here i get error saying

**"We have detected a problem with this shopping cart. If the problem persists, please contact the merchant. At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to xxl and try another option."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add a new variable called "upload"](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside#methodtwo), so it might look like:

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
...
```

Tried it, worked with your code in my PP-Sandbox.

Comment: yeah it worked, but crazy variable name "upload" totally confusing